# Domain Mapping with WPMU

Tags: multisite

I have a client who has approximately 50-75 independent dealers for their products.  The client is looking for a way to provide individual websites to their dealer network, and I was thinking to suggest going the route of WPMU.

Most of the dealers have an existing business that they incorporate their dealership into, and many already have their own domain names.

**My question is:**  Can you easily map the dealers' existing domain names to their corresponding WMPU website (so that a subdomain is never used/visible)?

Answer (score 0):

I've built similar network sites and the [Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) plugin works like a charm.

The only catch is that your network hub (the original site) can't be mapped to a different domain name, so keep that in mind when planning the sites/network.

Answer (score 0):

The Domain Mapping plugin is obsolete and should not be used with any WP installations newer than version 4.x.

[See this discussion](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/howto-domain-mapping-without-a-plugin-instructions/) at the plugin support forum.  Works great.